# SF Message Channel Error: Cannot find Lightning Component Bundle force-app

Tags: salesforce-lightning, lwc

I'm following a Lightning Web Component course and have been stuck on the Lightning Message Service lesson. After having created the messageChannels folder under force-app/main/default and creating the XML file, whenever I try to push the code (to either a Scratch Org or a Dev Org) I receive the error "Cannot find Lightning Component Bundle force-app".

I've searched frantically for an answer and none of the solutions online seem to help.

1. The XML file was copied and pasted from here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_lightningmessagechannel.htm
2. The package.xml file has also been copied and pasted from there (the applicable part)

3.The folder's name is spelled correctly and the file is aptly names as well (lwcChannel.messageChannel-meta.xml)

4. If I remove the messageChannels folder, pushing the code works normally.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!